# Part drawing information vs Assembly drawing

Tags: cad, technical-drawing, drafting, drawings

With my progress through various drawings, I finally came across an assembly drawing with parts I have actually drawn up that caught my eye.  The first part drawing as shown below is a simple sheet metal tube.

[image]

This is drawing 5521 E 12.  In the following Assembly drawing I see the tube called out along with other parts.  This seems to me to be perfectly reasonable for something called an assembly drawing.  Again, this is not my field so I am really not sure what belongs on the part drawing and what belongs on the assembly drawing.

[image]

What I noticed is that there are more features added to the part.  A dimple, a couple of holes, and some flanges added to the ends.  I thought all holes, dimples and anything that does not affect the way parts would come together would belong on the part drawing.  so I would have thought the dimple and holes should have been on the part drawing.  However, I believe the flange belongs on the assembly drawing as it would need to be added after 5520 E 13 has been slid into place.  Now my assumption could be complete hog wash.

**Is my assessment correct and the holes should have been on the parts drawing?  If not how do you determine which dimensions and features belong on parts drawings and which belong on assembly?**

Comment: It is possible to instruct users to modify parts in assembly.

Comment: It may be that more than one E12 part is used in the overall assembly, and in this case it needs these additional features which are not needed in the other places it's used.  So rather than create an additional part, they show modifications to the part where needed.

Comment: @mark  I had not considered that option.  Namely as I had seen a few parts that look very similar with either a minor dimensional change here or there, or one with holes and one without.  I had been left with the impressing that each unique part required its own part drawing.  Thanks for shedding light on an alternative